# Setting Connection strings using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices

Tags: ssis, connection-string

I am using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices` namespace to programmatically run my SSIS 2012 packages. Everything seems to work great but I have a requirement to dynamically set my connection strings at run-time.  I know there are easy ways to do this using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime` because there is a `Connections` property on the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package` class. There seems to be no similar equivalent in the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices`.

It seems using the parameter collection that the code below seems to do the trick:

```
project.Parameters["CM<myconnectionmanagername>.UserName"].Set(ParameterInfo.ParameterValueType.Literal, "user");              
project.Parameters["CM.<myconnectionmanagername>.Password"].Set(ParameterInfo.ParameterValueType.Literal, "password");
project.Parameters["CM<myconnectionmanagername>.ConnectionString"].Set(ParameterInfo.ParameterValueType.Literal, <your-full-connection-string-here>);   

project.Alter();
```

The problem with this solution is that all 3 parameters need to be set for the connection string to work. An obvious problem with this is that It forces me to parse connection strings to get the "user" and "password" piece the connection string. For a reusable system where there are many possible connection string formats the parsing code could get ugly. Is there a better/easier way to do this (setting connecting strings dynamically using the MOM in SSIS)?